# How to deal with WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, conditional-statements

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I am copy pasting C++ code to a new project to do a dll. The source code compiles and builds perfectly but I am having troubles to compile the new project despide it is the same code. The reason is one conditional statement which is not letting compile code and I do not know how to make it do it. It is like this:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
```

I assume that the statement is false so I do not get the underneath code compile and get errors. May you tell me how I can make it true so I can solve my errors?

Thank you.

Comment: This is set by the [compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561383.aspx), if you are setting this manually there is a major issue.

Comment: I am not aware of any change from my part concerning the compiler.

Comment: That macro is always defined, unless your project sets the WINAPI_FAMILY macro to WINAPI_FAMILY_APP.  Which will happen only in projects that target Windows Store or Windows Phone.  The #if directive helps you avoid using winapi functions that you cannot use in such an app.  Which are many.  Trying to patch around this is not useful, the sandbox enforces these restrictions, as does the verification procedure that your app is subjected to when you submit it.

Comment: @HansPassant you can see app functions available to desktop apps but not the other way around, regardless you have to set `/Zw` to make that available.

Comment: I am working over an dll (Universal Apps) project for Visual C++. Do you mean I have to change the type of project to make it work?. I can not do that since I need the project to be dll format, does nayone have a solution?

Comment: Hmm, no, /ZW just enables the C++/CX language extension.  Which is useful, but not required to write compatible libraries.  It is actually a project property sheet named "Windows Store app" that sets the macro.

Comment: And yes, a Universal App project is a WINAPI_FAMILY_APP.  You cannot use the winapi function that you like to use.  Do avoid asking an XY question.

Comment: Will I be able to find similar method on WINAPI_FAMILY_APP?, for instance, I needed for GetFileAttributes(), GetPrivateProfileString(), GetPrivateProfileInt() and CreateEvent().

Comment: I would start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx